# postgresql trigger by using 2 tables

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I have 3 tables:

1. Employee(eid, ename, salary, did, classification)
2. Project(pid, pname, did, budget, duedate)
3. Onproject(pid, eid, fromdate)

I try to  write trigger that checks on insert of a new employee to Onproject, that the duedate is greater than one month from fromdate, if not return a error message, and the record won't be added to the table.

I tried

```
CREATE TRIGGER T1
BEFORE INSERT
ON Onproject
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigf1();

create or replace function trigf1() returns trigger as
$BODY$ BEGIN
IF (DATE_PART('day', NEW.fdate::date) - DATE_PART('day', duedate::date) > 30)
THEN insert into Onproject values (NEW.pid, NEW.eid, NEW.fdate)
else
rais notice 'adding employee to the project failed, less then one month to due date.'
end if
end
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL VOLATILE
```

but the trigger doesn't know the duedate field and the Project table.

How can I create the trigger by using the Project and Onproject tables?

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning anything from the trigger. If you want the INSERT to proceed simply return the `new` row, if you want it to fail, you need to raise an error.

You also need to run a select on the project table to retrieve the duedate, you can't just take it out of thin air:

```
create or replace function trigf1() returns trigger as
$BODY$ 
declare
  l_duedate date;
BEGIN
  -- get the duedate for the project
  select duedate 
    into l_duedate
  from project
  where pid = new.pid;

  IF l_duedate > NEW.fromdate::date + interval '1 month'
  THEN  
     -- everything OK, proceed with the insert
     return new;
  end if;

  -- using raise error, aborts the transaction
  raise error 'adding employee to the project failed, less then one month to due date.'
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL VOLATILE
```